# std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> holding both dynamically and statically allocated Foo

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

I have a base class Updater:

```
class Updater : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Updater>
{
    virtual void update(void) = 0;
};
```

With lots of derivates, most dynamically created, but some statically created.  These get registered to perform some batched updates into:

```
class DispatchGroup {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Updater>> m_dispatchList;
};
```

Given a derivate class:

```
class UpdaterDerivate : public Updater {...};
```

**How should I create a statically defined instance of UpdaterDerivate which can safely participate in the DispatchGroup::m_dispatchList?**

Initialization ordering isn't a problem (DispatchGroups can only be dynamically created), so the concern is how to avoid having m_dispatchList destruction try to destruct (and free) my statically allocated UpdaterDerivates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create it with a deleter that does nothing:

```
struct NullDeleter // Or use <boost/core/null_deleter.hpp>
{ 
    template<class T> 
    void operator()(T*) const { /* do nothing */ }
};
```

And then:

```
UpdaterDerivate a;
std::shared_ptr<Updater> pa(&a, NullDeleter{});
```

Comment: Doesn't that require everyone who is using shared_from_this() to be aware of the allocation type?  Or is the deleter somehow conveyed through the shared_ptr internals?

Comment: @Speed8ump The latter.

Comment: @Speed8ump [std::enable_shared_from_this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this): _If an object t of type T is managed by a std::shared_ptr<T> named pt, then calling T::shared_from_this will return a new std::shared_ptr<T> that shares ownership of t with pt._